# Upgrading Weblogic 10.3.6 to 12c

Tags: weblogic, upgrade, weblogic11g, weblogic12c

I have a Weblogic 10.3.6 installation with a single domain. To upgrade it to 12c, I downloaded the 12c installer but I can't seem to find upgrade.cmd or upgrade.sh in the common/bin folder. The documentation refers to running upgrade.cmd/sh to upgrade the domain. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason, using the upgrade didn't work well for me. So what I did was:

- Install weblogic 12c binaries from 
  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/fusion-middleware/downloads/index.html
- unzip the file somewhere (d:/weblogic12c/wls12120)
- Have a version of JDK installed (you can use 1.7 with 12c)
- Add the following Environment variables 
  JAVA_HOME : path/to/jdk_folder
  JAVA_HOME/bin
  MW_HOME : path/to/weblogic_installation (d:/weblogic12c/wls12120)
- Have a copy of the old domain (you want to keep)
- Run configure.cmd/configure.sh, create a new domain.
- Delete the new domain folder, and copy your old domain folder.
- make sure weblogic12c start scripts are using the right jdk installation.

I don't know why, but this worked better for me than running the upgrade script, it guess its cleaner to start with a new installation, as long as you can copy the domain, you won't loose it.

Hope that helps.